# How to physically turn the a Raspberry Touch display on and off?

Tags: power, display, touchscreen, electronics, switches

I use a Raspberry Pi Touch Display that I connect like shown in the following picture to my Raspberry. The black and red wires are connected to thee GND and 5v pins respectively. Now I want to physically turn off the display while the raspberry is still running.

[image]

In the future, I'd like to use a switch for that. But to test it, I just tried unplugging the red/+ wire. Unplugging the wire turns the display off as expected. However, if I plug the wire back in, the display is not turned on again. Why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the post linked below, the display requires some software initialization on the Pi side. When you reconnect the power to the display, there is no way for the Pi to know it is supposed to reinitialize it.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=120296

Further down in the thread, you can find the terminal commands to turn the display off and on:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

If you'd like to use a switch to turn the display off, I'd suggest making a script to detect when the switch has been moved and then run the correct command from above.